# Error when compiling sample code "SourceView"

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, xcode8

I tried to download and compile https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SourceView/Introduction/Intro.html

I have:
Xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a)
macOS Sierra 10.12 Beta (16A313a)

I get the following error:

> /Users/test/Downloads/SourceViewUsingNSOutlineViewwithNSTreeController/SourceView/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard:
>   Exception while running ibtool: [<__NSCFConstantString 0x10db4cca0>
>   valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant
>   for the key nodeTitle.

Does anyone has a clue on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

According to QuinceyMorris @ https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/62880:

> It's some kind of bug compiling storyboards in older formats. The only
>   workaround I found (in a different project) was to set the file format
>   to 10.12 (in the File panel of the Utility inspector) instead of the
>   deployment target version. (FWIW the 10.12 format worked OK on 10.11,
>   too, perhaps only by luck.)

I created the following radar:

- 28316038 to update sample code
- 28316077 to dup #19669391